# android oboe - how to set an andio song as stream for playing

Tags: android

I am using [oboe](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/introducing-oboe-c-library-for-low.html) and i want to create an audio stream that will flow as an INPUT to the user.  but im having trouble setting an mp3 file as an audio stream. how can i do it ? here is what i have so far per the [sample docs](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md):

```
oboe::AudioStream *stream;
oboe::Result result = builder.openStream(&stream);
```

how can i set the stream to an audio file. i must first convert the file into a stream ? but which stream? there is ByteArrayInputStream and there is BufferedInputStream , etc. can someone provide an example ?
also is there a setting to input directly into the microphone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oboe and AAudio will not read from an MP3 file. They are designed for input and output to physical audio devices.

Try the Media APIs on Android for reading an MP3 file.

Comment: i wanted to inject sound into the microphone while the user speaks on a call.  i guess this is not the  library for it right ?

Comment: Right. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791922/android-transmit-sound-to-somebody-during-a-call